# Are measures better thought of as densities than differentials?

Tags: measure-theory, notation

The standard notation for integrating with respect to a measure $\mu$ is:

$$\int f(x)\,d\mu(x).$$

But I've wondered if it could be better written as:

$$\int f(x)\mu(x)\,dx$$

where $\mu(x)$ is now thought of as a *density*. Then applying the measure $\mu$ to a set $A$ can be expressed as $\int \mathbf 1_A(x) \mu(x)\,dx$ or $\langle \mathbf 1_A, \mu\rangle$.

In particular, if $\mu$ is the Dirac $\delta$ measure, then integrating with respect to $\delta$ can be written $\int f(x)\delta(x)\,dx$ instead of the more awkward $\int f(x)\,d\delta(x)$. If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then we can denote it as $1$, and write $\int f(x)\cdot 1\,dx$ for the integral of $f$ with respect to $1$. If $\mu$ is a probability measure $p$, then we can write $\int f(x)p(x)\,dx$ for $\mathbb E_p[f(X)]$.

Regarding Stieltjes measures, the appropriate notation for the Stieltjes measure of a monotonic right-continuous function $g$ is $g'$, not $dg$.

I got this idea from reading the nLab entry on the Radon-Nikodym Theorem. There, it's pointed out that the Radon-Nikodym "derivative" of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ can be written as $\frac\nu\mu$. Notice that when written this way, it doesn't actually look like a derivative. So perhaps, the terminology "Radon-Nikodym derivative" is misleading. Besides, if it were really useful to see it as a derivative, then surely it would satisfy the product rule, **but it doesn't**.

Are there any disadvantages of this notation?

Comment: What would be the advantage, really? Although I'm an analyst I personally also like the probabilistic notation $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$

Comment: @leomonsaingeon To me that reads "Sum of $f(x)$ times $\mu(dx)$" where $\mu(dx)$ doesn't make much sense on its own, but maybe I'm being too literal. I like to think of $\int f(x)\,dx$ as literally being the sum of $f(x)$ times $dx$

Comment: yes, precisely! the only difference between a "sum" and the more rigorous integral formalism is that $\mu(dx)$ is the ininitesimal mass contained in the infinitesimal set $dx$ (in fact as far as I can tell probabilists often write $dx$ for measurable sets, so non infinitesimal at all) After all, an integral is nothing but a fancier weighted sum, is it not? (the $\int$ sign is even reminiscent from that idea)

Comment: @leomonsaingeon I guess that makes sense. But now you can't write $\int f(x) \, dx$ because $dx$ is some "infinitesimal" set. You have to write $\int f(x) \mu(dx)$. But I guess that apart from that awkwardness, it could work

Comment: Well, this is some kind of residual notational ambiguity due to the fact that, when one learns integration, usually the Lebesgue integral is given a priviledged role (for obvious historical and convenience reasons). For example (some) probabilists would never actually write $\int f(x) dx$, but rather $\int f(x)\lambda(dx)$ or $\int f(x) \mathcal L^d(dx)$, where $\lambda$ or $\mathcal L^d$ stand for the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Actually the second notation is somehow also standard in geometric measure theory and calculus of variations, especially in the Italian school.

Comment: For me its a strange discussion. The proposal seems only to make sense if we have probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ or some locally compact group. But what if we have a measure on an abstract measure space $(\Omega,\cal{A})$? Then $dx$ with respect to what?

Comment: The Radon-Nikodym derivative has its name obviously from the fundamental theorem of calculus. I have never seen someone getting confused by the name.